# Integração software website Java

Tags: java, html

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:
Eu e minha equipe estamos desenvolvendo um software que analisa uma tabela com dados específicos, porem para gerar essa tabela nós utilizamos um website onde você entra uma informação e esse website analisa e gera todos os dados sobre essa informação em forma de tabela em html.
A maioria de nós tem conhecimento básico e intermediário de java, então gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de fazer um programa que vá receber a entrada, consultar esse website, entrar a informação passada, coletar o resultado em html e devolver somente esse resultado já pronto.

Edit:
Aqui tá a parte do meu código que faz a conexão, o site recebe uma sequencia genética, processa e depois devolve uma tabela em html. O que eu quero é que meu sistema se conecte, envie a sequencia e capture a resposta.

```
package wangConn;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class WangConnection {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String param1 = "ATGCCCCCGACGCCCCCGGGGGGTGA", param2="Submit";
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        // Mounting content to be sent
        String data = "seqfield=" + URLEncoder.encode(param1, "UTF-8");
        data += "Submit=" + URLEncoder.encode(param2, "UTF-8");

        url = new URL("http://wangcomputing.com/assp/");
        // Make connection with the specified URL
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        // Enable writing on URLConnection
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        // Connect using the POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        // Define the requisition type
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        // Send data
        out = new DataOutputStream(
                connection.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(data);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        // Getting return from the connection
        String line;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Bad format URL: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to connect: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        if(out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to close input stream: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if(in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to close output stream: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        connection.disconnect();
    }
  }
}
```

Meu problema agora é que o website que eu estou tentando submeter o form no website sem sucesso.
O tipo de input usado:

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Sua pergunta está um tanto quanto ampla @LuBu, e esse tipo de questão não se encaixa muito bem na proposta do site. Tente dividir seu problema em partes, desenvolver alguns código e caso encontre dúvidas específicas poste aqui. Comece fazendo um [tour] e leia [ask]. Abraço.

Comment: sua pergunta não está ampla, está obscura e não técnica.
você quer buscar dados de uma pagina, ok
você precisa informar como esse acesso é feito, get ou post e se existe autenticação. depois a sua duvida e como pegar o html analisar e extrair alguma informação.

Comment: Basicamente o que eu procuro é uma maneira de o meu sistema acessar uma pagina web, inserir o conteúdo que essa pagina pede para gerar um resultado, capturar esse resultado e trazer de volta pro meu sistema.
Ou seja, quero que meu sistema utilize uma pagina da web pra gerar um resultado que será utilizado numa outra parte do sistema depois.
Não quero código pronto nem nada disso, simplesmente saber se isso é possível e onde posso aprender sobre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa entrar na URL e capturar a informação dentro do elemento que você quer. Veja como acessar uma URL em java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL url;
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader br;
    String line;

    try {
        url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
        is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
         mue.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null) is.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // nothing to see here
        }
    }
}
```

Quando você tiver o HTML, você pode querer filtrá-lo. Olhe esse link mostrando uma alternativa. [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)

```
String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();

String text = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"
String linkHref = link.attr("href"); // "http://example.com/"
String linkText = link.text(); // "example""

String linkOuterH = link.outerHtml(); 
    // "<a href="http://example.com"><b>example</b></a>"
String linkInnerH = link.html(); // "<b>example</b>"
```